# How to check if a controller has put with Flutter GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have the following code:

```
Get.put(DbController(HabitDao(AppDb())));
```

When I hot reload my app, I get the following error:

```
"WARNING (moor): It looks like you've created the database class AppDb multiple times. When these two databases use the same QueryExecutor, race conditions will occur and might corrupt the database."
```

I need to check if I have put a `DbController` before creating a new `AppDb` instance. I never had this problem while using the Provider package.

What is the best practice to solve this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can check with `Get.isRegistered`.

For your code:

```
bool test = Get.isRegistered<DbController>(tag: 'TagInPut');
```

If you didn't use tag, you can delete it.

```
bool test = Get.isRegistered<DbController>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful while writing widget test when you want to use your mocked controller instead of putting a controller in screen

```
late ParentProfileController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (Get.isRegistered<ParentProfileController>()) {
      controller = Get.find<ParentProfileController>();
    } else {
      controller = Get.put(ParentProfileController());
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```